# Multi-Boot & BIOS Attack Vector Risks For Bitcoin Wallet Storage

Tags: bios, bitcoin

I'm trying to emulate a cold storage computer for crypto assets with a multi-boot computer.

If I have multi-OS boots & the 'cold storage' boot is never connected to the internet when it is booted, is it possible for a compromised BIOS to store information when booted to the cold storage OS & then leak it once booted to a OS connected to the internet?

Comment: Why is it called a cold storage if it resides on the same storage accessible by your "hot OS"? although I admit that's an extra layer of hassle post to attacker..

Comment: @Sajuuk If there's a lot of money involved, an attacker won't mind the hassle.

Comment: I forgot to put quotes around hassle. sorry.

Comment: If I added this protection to the computer, could we close the BIOS loss vector: https://shop.puri.sm/shop/librem-key/